# RecyclerView Adapter is loading every time firebase database data gets updated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am new to firebase. I am trying to update my RecyclerView data in the firebase database while reflecting the same updated value in my RecyclerView data dynamically.  Even in case of someone tries to update the data from firebase console itself, the change has to be reflected in the recyclerView.
        I have a seekBar in my list and every time i change the data from the list, it has to be reflected back in the database. The problem is, every time i am trying to change the data from the recyclerView list itself, data is getting changed in the firebase database which in turn calling the onDataChanged() and its making my whole recyclerView getting reloaded again without showing the updated data on the list. Please help.

```
    Below  I am posting my listfragment as well as adapter class code:

    ListFragment:

         @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment

            View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_slc_list, container, false);
            slcList = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.addedSlcList);
            noSLC = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.noSLCText);
            fragmentManager= myContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
            slcList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            ref = new Firebase(Config.FIREBASE_URL);
            list = new ArrayList<slcItem>();
            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    //        dAdapter = new slcListAdapter(myContext,list, ref );
    //        slcList.setLayoutManager(llm);
    //        slcList.setAdapter(dAdapter);
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    Log.d("clear","cleared");
                    list.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Log.v("2nd",""+ childDataSnapshot.getKey()); //displays the key for the node
                        Log.v("2nd",""+ childDataSnapshot.getValue());
                        Slc val= childDataSnapshot.getValue(Slc.class);
                        Log.v("2ndClass",""+ val.getOn_off());
                        slcItem item = new slcItem();
                        item.setSlcOnOff(val.getOn_off());
                        item.setSlcID(val.getUser_id());
                        item.setSlcProgress(val.getDimming_val());
                        item.setSlcName(childDataSnapshot.getKey());
                        item.setSlcStatus(val.getStatus());
                        list.add(item);
                        LinearLayoutManager llm1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        dAdapter = new slcListAdapter(myContext,list, ref );
                        dAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        slcList.setLayoutManager(llm1);
                        slcList.setAdapter(dAdapter);
                    }
                    for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++)
                    {
                        Log.d("animesh",list.get(i).getSlcName()+" "+list.size()+" "+dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    }
                    if(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() == 0)
                    {
                        LinearLayoutManager llm1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        dAdapter = new slcListAdapter(myContext,list, ref );
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                dAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                        slcList.setLayoutManager(llm1);
                        slcList.setAdapter(dAdapter);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError)
                {
                    Log.d("animesh",firebaseError+"");
                }
            });
            Log.d("anilist",list.size()+"");
```

---

```
Adapter class:

    public slcListAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<slcItem> list, Firebase ref ) {
        super();
        this.context=context;
        this.list=list;
        this.ref=ref;

        dItems = new ArrayList<slcItem>();
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            slcItem deal = new slcItem();
        deal.setSlcName(list.get(i).getSlcName());
        dItems.add(deal);
        }



        }

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.single_slc_row, viewGroup, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
        }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        int v;

         nature = dItems.get(i);
         ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Log.d("animesh",childDataSnapshot.toString());
                    Slc val = childDataSnapshot.getValue(Slc.class);
//                    viewHolder.dimming.setProgress(val.getDimming_val());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

            }
        });

        viewHolder.name.setText(nature.getSlcName());
        viewHolder.inv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        viewHolder.onOff.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                         boolean isChecked) {
                Log.d("checkani",nature.getSlcName());
                if(isChecked){
                    ref.child(list.get(i).getSlcName()).child("on_off").setValue(1);


                }else{
                    ref.child(list.get(i).getSlcName()).child("on_off").setValue(0);
                    Log.d("Ani",list.get(i).getSlcName());
                }

            }
        });
    viewHolder.dimming.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
        {
           Log.d("dimming",nature.getSlcName());

            ref.child(list.get(i).getSlcName()).child("dimming_val").setValue(progress);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
        viewHolder.expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               // ViewAnimationsUtils.expand(viewHolder.inv);
                viewHolder.collapse.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.inv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.expand.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
        viewHolder.collapse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
               // ViewAnimationsUtils.collapse(inv);
                viewHolder.inv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.expand.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.collapse.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    viewHolder.edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.update_slc);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            if(window == null) return;
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            final EditText name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.slcNameu);
            final EditText id = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.slcIDu);
            TextView cancel = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelu);
            TextView update = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.updateSlc);
//            update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(View v)
//                {
//                    final String Sname = nature.getSlcName();
//                    Map mParent = new HashMap();
//                    mParent.put("user_id", id.getText().toString().trim());
//                    mParent.put("on_off", nature.getSlcOnOff());
//                    mParent.put("status", nature.getSlcStatus());
//                    mParent.put("dimming_val",nature.getSlcProgress());
//                    ref.child(name.getText().toString().trim()).setValue(mParent, new Firebase.CompletionListener()
//                    {
//                        @Override
//                        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
//                            Log.d("aniNature","Value was set. Error = "+firebaseError+" "+nature.getSlcName()+" "+Sname);
//                            ref.child(Sname).removeValue();
//                            dialog.dismiss();
//                        }
//                    });
//
//                }
//            });
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            dialog.show();

        }
    });
    viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setTitle("Delete Slc?");
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.delete_slc);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            Window window = dialog.getWindow();
            if(window == null) return;
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            TextView delete = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.deleteSlc);
            delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Log.d("delete1",nature.getSlcName());
                    ref.child(list.get(i).getSlcName()).removeValue();
                    Log.d("delete",nature.getSlcName());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });


            TextView dialogButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.canceld);
            // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
            dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            dialog.show();
        }
    });

        }

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{

        return dItems.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView name;
    public Switch onOff;
    public SeekBar dimming;
    public TextView edit;
    public TextView delete;
    public TextView expand;
    public TextView collapse;
    public LinearLayout inv;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slcName);
        onOff = (Switch) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slcONOFFSwich);
        dimming=(SeekBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.slcDimming);
        edit = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.EditSlc);
        delete = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.DeleteSlc);
        expand = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.down);
        collapse = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.up);
        inv = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.invisibleLayout);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: please checkout addListenerForSingleValueEvent for Firebase

Comment: @LalitJadav Thank you thank you....:), But its not working for changes like deletion or updation at the console page.

Comment: It reads data only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to respond to child-level changes, you should use a [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#child-events). This interface has separate methods for when a child is added, removed, changed or moved (`onChildAdded`, `onChildRemoved`, `onChildChanged` and `onChildMoved` respectively).

Note that you'll need to do a lot more work in this scenario to ensure the items stay in the correct order in `list`. For example: you'll need to track the key of each item, so that you can compare it to `previousKey` argument in `onChildAdded` and `onChildChanged`.

For an example of a working implementation of such an adapter, I recommend checking out FirebaseUI's [`FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java) and its underlying [`FirebaseArray`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseArray.java).

Comment: Thank you, the recyclerView is now dynamic, but while I am trying to delete an item from the recyclerView, I am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException @Frank

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `addValueEventListener` use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` this will only get your data from Firebase once and will **not** listen for updates.

Check [this website for detailed documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

> Reading Data Once
>
> In some cases it may be useful for a callback to be called once and then immediately removed. We've created a helper function to make this easy:

```
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    // ...
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // ...
}
});
```

Comment: Its working fine but again its not working for changes like deletion or updation at the console page.@Ruben Aalders

Comment: Okay, I might not be fully understanding your problem. Could you elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: When you are changing something in the recyclerView, it will be reflected in the database. Similarly If you are changing something in the database , that has to be reflected back in the RecyclerView Item as well like updating or deleting an item.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this in listener:

```
LinearLayoutManager llm1 = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                        dAdapter = new slcListAdapter(myContext,list, ref );
                        dAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        slcList.setLayoutManager(llm1);
                        slcList.setAdapter(dAdapter);
```

This will set new adapter every time data changed. You have to maintain list and keep track on that list. Every time item changes occur just edit it in your list and notify only those changes.

No need to create new adapter every time

Answer (score 0):

You can add a child event listener so that it will only set the model to the list if a child node event is triggered from the database, I have this as an example from my code of posts:

```
 @Override
                     public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
                         //if the current user likes the post, then update the post with like value
                         if (snapshot.getKey().equals(myUid)) {
                             postList.get(i).setpLikes(""+snapshot.getChildrenCount());
                             notifyItemChanged(i, postList.get(i));
                         } else {
                             //if the current user does not like the post, then update the post with like value
                             postList.get(i).setpLikes(""+snapshot.getChildrenCount());
                             notifyItemChanged(i, postList.get(i));
                             
                         }
                     }
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.